# The cards are not responsive

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

```js
function Team() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1 className='text-center font-bold    text-2xl'>Meet the Team</h1>
    <div className='p-3 m-3 flex space-x-10'>

      <div className="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
        <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
        <div className="p-5">
          <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Aadya Sharma </h5>
          <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div className="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
        <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
        <div className="p-5">
          <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Shikhar singh</h5>
          <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div className="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
        <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
        <div className="p-5">
          <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Hemant S. Rathod</h5>
          <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  );
};

export default Team;
```

This is a code for a collections of card which are in rows at in desktop view but i want them to be in columns when it is phone view . i am using react with tailwind css.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cards to be in a single column on mobile devices and then on larger devices to be in row, there are a couple of ways to do that: flexbox and grid are probably the easiest.

One way that you can use flexbox would be to set the flex-direction to column (by adding the class `flex-col`) and then for some larger breakpoint change the direction to row and add flex-wrap.  In TailwindCSS you use the breakpoint (e.g., sm, md, lg, xl, 2xl) followed by a colon and then the property to apply at that breakpoint (e.g., `md:flex-row md:flex-wrap`).

#### Working snippet with flexbox (run and then open in full screen to test responsiveness):

```js
function Team() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center text-2xl font-bold">Meet the Team</h1>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-6 p-3 md:flex-row md:flex-wrap">
        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Aadya Sharma</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Shikhar singh</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Hemant S. Rathod</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Team/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Grid would give you more control over the number of columns to display at each breakpoint.  For example, you could have 1 column for extra small screens, 2 columns for small and medium screens and then on large screen have 4 columns.  To do that you'd use: `grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 p-3 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4`.

#### Working snippet with grid:

```js
function Team() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center text-2xl font-bold">Meet the Team</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 p-3 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Aadya Sharma</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Shikhar singh</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className=" mx-auto max-w-sm rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800">
          <img className="rounded-t-lg" src="https://media.vanityfair.com/photos/6319eab06009e759e6638e28/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/1421315651" alt="" />
          <div className="p-5">
            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Hemant S. Rathod</h5>
            <p className="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Team/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```